# TypeScript SES User is not authorized to perform ses:SendEmail on resource

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, web, backend, amazon-ses

I am trying to use AWS SES to send email. I was wondering why I have error TypeScript SES User is not authorized to perform  ses:SendEmail on resource. What do I have to do? Do I have to authenticate the aws config like accesskeyID and secret access key? If so, how do I do it? I am new to these.

The email test@test.com is something that I changed for this post but is different.

```
import { SES, AWSError} from 'aws-sdk';
import { SendEmailRequest, SendEmailResponse } from 'aws-sdk/clients/ses';

export const sendEmail = (email: string) =>{

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const REGION = "us-east-1";

const charset = "UTF-8"

const html = "<h1>Hello</h1>"

const ses = new SES({region:REGION});

const params: SendEmailRequest = {
    Source: "test@test.com",
    Destination: {
        ToAddresses: [
            email
        ]
    },
    Message: {
        Subject: {
            Data: "Welcome to Website",
            Charset: charset
        },
        Body: {
            Text: {
                Data: "WELCOME TO Website!!!",
                Charset: charset
            },
            Html: {
                Data: html,
                Charset: charset
            }
        }
    }
}
ses.sendEmail(params, (err: AWSError, data: SendEmailResponse) => {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else console.log(data);
});

}
```

Comment: That error means that you did authenticate to aws (either via role or local credentials file), but your user didn't have that permission. You need to update the policy for your role or user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to pass credentials somehow. There are various methods how to do it described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html.

You also have to use IAM user that has `ses:SendEmail` permison.

The last thing you need to do is to verify domain used as a source. It also can cause some errors(I guess you don't own @test.com domain). Description how to do it can be found at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html

Comment: I got my credentials, but I am not sure how to apply them in TypeScript.

Comment: Easiest way is to load them from json file like this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-json-file.html or have them stored in ~/. aws/credentials like this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html